# Сравнить текущие время с заданным

Tags: php

Необходимо сравнить текущие время с заданным, если текущие время больше заданного хотя бы больше на  30 минут, то вывести фразу. 
У меня выводит такую ошибку  Call to a member function format() on boolean. Подскажите, где я не прав

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = date($DB->DateFormatToPHP(CSite::GetDateFormat("FULL")), time()); // выводит дату в формате сайта 08.09.2017 10:17:57 
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$m = $interval->format('%i');
$h = $interval->format('%h');
if($m > 30 || $h > 1){
  echo "time";
}
```

Comment: а до этого скорее всего должен писать ошибку `type 2 -- DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given`  потому что ты даешь в параметр строку, а нужно DateTime

Comment: Для начала проверьте, что Вам функции CMS возвращают

Comment: вот не надо менять вопрос по ходу пьесы

Comment: простите ошибку у себя заметил, поэтому изменил код

Comment: Зачем вообще такая муть? Две метки времени сверили и все. 30 минут = 1800 секунд.

Comment: @ChromeChrome для другого вопроса задавай другой вопрос, не стоит править текущий..... однако увидев что там было могу сказать что там ошибка естесственна...т.к. ты пытался применить `diff` на строках, а не на объектах `DateTime`

Comment: @Visman не стоит недооценивать всю мощь авторской мысли))

Comment: всем спасибо разобрался)

Answer (score 0):

Замени

```
$datetime2 = date($DB->DateFormatToPHP(CSite::GetDateFormat("FULL")), time());
```

на

```
$datetime2 = new DateTime($DB->DateFormatToPHP(CSite::GetDateFormat("FULL")), time());
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что `$datetime2` передается как строка, а надо тоже как `DateTime`

```
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date($DB->DateFormatToPHP(CSite::GetDateFormat("FULL")), time())); 
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```